# Mysql DB Is this the most efficient design?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have an existing `mysql` DB that manages regulations for 50 states. The current setup is relational - three tables for EACH of the 50 states:

`state_table` contains the chapter/sub-chapter headings
`item_table` contains the end records
`department_table` contains the ID's to relate the two.

all combined it handles around 620,000 records

I'm not a DB design expert and have always utilized this as-is and gotten-by however, the nature of tables for all 50 states limits searching across all states etc. and I'm wondering if there is a better approach.

I'm wondering if I should consider combining this into either a single set of 3 relational tables for the entire nation or even a single table to handle everything.

I've asked this on other forums and have been told to read various volumes of DB schema and structures etc. so if there is someone who can just suggest the direction to go in and the pro's and con's of what I have vs the alternative that would be great!

thanks!

Here's the way it is, X 50

alabama

> ID
>   Name
>   State
>   Parent 
>   Description

alabama_department

> Department - ID's from "alabama"
>
> Item - ID's from "alabama_item"

alabama_item

> ID
>   Name
>   Description
>   Keywords
>   Doc_ID
>   Effective_date
>     ...
>     ...

The Queries: I step through the heirarchy of chapter/sub-chapter/end-record via links this works fine but I'm starting to focus more on search capability and also thinking what I have is overkill and it sounds like a couple of you think so (overkill)

Comment: can you post the existing table structures?  And some details about how you want to query this data?

Comment: Providing your actual schema would help. Outside of that, can you better describe some *specific* deficiencies in your current schema? I can't glean those from your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am correct in thinking you have 150 tables (3 * 50 states) Then:

You should have a 'states' table which includes a `stateID` and `stateName`. Then use ONE table for chapter/subchapters, ONE for departments, and ONE for end records and use the `stateID` to relate different records to a state.

You should **not** have 3 tables for each state, you can use one of each and just relate to a state table. This brings you to four tables instead of 150.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `alabama` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` blob,
  `DisplayPrecedence` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3351 ;

Comment: Sorry hit enter... still gathering some info for the

Comment: ^ That is **not** what you want. You do not need a new table for every state.

Comment: ok, I also edited/added a better example up in my post. so... still keep the relational just put all states chapters/sub-chapters together and all states end-records together and one relational table between the two correct ?

Comment: What I wrote still stands. It will bring you to 4 tables instead of ~150. You will have to create 4 new tables and reorganize your data, but it will be WAY better.

Comment: Ok I get most of that but for some reason I'm hung up on the "use the stateID to relate different records to a state."  can you provide a simple description or example of that to clarify .

Comment: Instead of `alabama_department` use `department`. Then in `department` have a `stateid` column which matches the `stateid` on the `states` table. That way you know which record in `department` goes to which state.